# Symfony2 - Database level onDelete Cascade doesn't trigger LifeCycle Events

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I've got two entites (simplified for this question) :
Folder :

```
class Folder {
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File",mappedBy="folder")
     **/
    private $files;
}
```

File :

```
class File {
    /**
     * @var Folder
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Folder",inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     **/
    private $folder;
}
```

I'm using database-level cascading to manage entity cascading.

I've made an event listener to be triggered when a « File » is deleted (in order to remove a MongoDB Document associated with the entity « File »)

Here that eventListener :

```
class MysqlMongoDBIntegrity{

    /**
     * @var DocumentManager
      */
     private $_odm;
     /**
      * @var EntityManager
      */
    private $_em;
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface
     */
    public function setODMManager(DocumentManager $manager)
    {
        $this->_odm = $manager;
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $this->_em = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof File) {

            /** @var MongoDocumentRepository $mongoRepo */
            $mongoRepo = $this->_odm->getRepository('MYBundle:MongoDocument');
            $mongoRepo->removeMongoDocument($entity->getMongoDocumentId());
        }
    }
}
```

The event is fired as expected when removing « File » entity directly. But, when removing a « Folder » entity, the cascading specified as database-level doesn't trigger the events.

Is there any way, without changing the cascading in @JoinColumn, to trigger this event ?

I know that delegating the cascading to Doctrine (cascade={"remove"}) would be better to triggers events, but is it possible to do that without replacing cascading in @Join annotation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite normal as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571334/different-in-annotation-symfony-2-doctrine-2/20571418#20571418) : in doctrine2, database level configured cascade don't raise lifecycle events, whether you use ORM or ODM. So it's not possible without replacing cascading in @Join annotations

Comment: OK, considering that, does defining cascading as database level AND orm/odm level will cause any conflicts ? => Sould I replace ALL @JoinColum(onDelete="CASCADE") with @«Relation»(cascade={"remove"}) or can i keep the two definitions ?

Comment: That's a good point. I don't know yet if using both the `onDelete` and `cascade=remove` can operate together. I think you can give it a try, and tell here if using both mapping works?

Comment: So I've done a little test, i've added : `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File",mappedBy="folder",cascade={"remove"})` on Folder's $files attribute and no conflicts seem to be noticed. I may conclude that the two cascading methods can work together without problems.

Comment: Thank you too, but it's a very simple test. Maybe, in more complicated cases, it could probably fail for any reasons (for example: in transactionnal context, or with huge ArrayCollection, etc.). I don't know how Doctrine manage cascading so i can't affirm that the two way of cascading are fully compatible... A Symfony2 expert may have the right answer about that.

Comment: It would be more a Doctrine2 expert in this case :) I know that the unit of work performs all the cascade on the flush, but I should inspect more the code to understand the underlying logic.